# Stay on current page after POST

Tags: php, post

I have a form which once the Submit button is pressed, it goes to a blank page and returns any error messages on that blank page. However I have a website template and I wish that my script is run, and returns the the page which did the action POST and puts any error messages on that page.

Example of what is happening:
PAGE REQUESTS POST ----> SCRIPT RUNS ---> RETURNS ERROR MESSAGE

What I want it to do is:
PAGE REQUESTS POST ---> SCRIPT RUNS ----> GOES TO THE PAGE WHICH REQUESTED POST ----> SHOWS ANY ERROR MESSAGES WHICH THE SCRIPT PICKED OUT.

Comment: if i undestanded what you want you should submit the page to the same script as the one that shows the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just set the Action of your form to the current page. Then the `$_POST` will contain all the values the user filled in the form.

Comment: I prefer to keep my scripts seperate, is there any other way?

Comment: Use include, and you can keep them separate.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: You are a clever man! I totally forgot about Include!

Comment: I got a question though, how do I check if POST has been called? My script is running itself without POST even on there.

Comment: Using `isset` you could check if any key from the form you submitted exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. I assume your are going to a blank page, because your POST goes to a PHP script different from the page it is posting from.

Option 1 - Post to the same PHP page as the page your are posting from.

Option 2 - Once you have posted, and generate an error, redirect back to the page, with the errors stored in a session, or a cookie, so that they can be rendered on the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the page containing the request form is also able to display the error messages, set the form attribute to the url of the page containing the form (as TJHeuvel noted) or just make action attribute empty, e.g, `<form action="">`.

Answer (score 0):

After going to blank page store all the posted variables in your variable say `$get` with syntax `param1=value1&param2=value2 and so on...`and redirect back by `header("Location: back.php?$get");` and in your main page by $_GET echo all the vars